# Transition CSS not working on blackberry 10

Tags: html, css, blackberry, css-transitions

I have an icon that, once tapped, opens a sidebar. I'm using this CSS3 transition:

```
transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
```

The sidebar is not working on BlackBerry devices but when I visit http://tympanus.net/Development/SidebarTransitions/ these sidebars works properly on a BlackBerry device.

The only difference in the animation is that the tympanus one has not the `ease-in-out` rule but just `transition: transform .2s;`

Any suggestions or other things to check?

Comment: If you remove `ease-in-out` on yours, does it work?

Comment: Also, did you try using the webkit prefix `-webkit-transition`?

Comment: Which effect is the one you are trying to implement?

Comment: Blackberry versions older than 10 need the webkit prefix ... that might also explain the different behavior

Comment: Yes, of course script does/can make a difference ... very often used as a fallback for browsers that does not support a certain CSS property